marginal analysis in Econ
Apparently in economics the derivative $f'(x)$ is often used to estimate $f(x+1)-f(x)$.
Say $f(x)$ is profit from $x$ items, then $f'(x)$ estimates profit from the $(x+1)$st item.
I am teaching this, and my problem is that this estimate can be very inaccurate, even for $f$ being a quartic function. When $f$ is exponential, then it is very inaccurate.
What would someone well versed in Econ say about this? Why use an inaccurate estimate, when I could just use $f(x+1)-f(x)$?
Thank you.

Keep in mind that sometimes you only know $f'(x)$.

Usually in economics you assume that goods are perfectly divisible so you can increase profits by infinitesimal quantity in which case this is exactly captured by derivative.

Hmm, in what scenario can it happen that we only know f'(x) but not f(x)? Thank you!

The point of the estimate
$$
f(x+h) \approx f(x) + f'(x)h
$$
is to say something about the value of $f$ near $x$ when all you know is information about $f$ at $x$.
The approximation is useful only when the change $h$ is small relative to the value of $x$. The estimate with $h=1$ is actually quite good for the exponential function
$
f(t) = e^{rt}
$
when $r$ is small relative to $t$. Then it says
$$
e^{r(t+1)} \approx e^{rt} + re^{rt} = (1+r)e^{rt}.
$$
In economics you would recognize that as using simple interest rather than continuously compounded interest. The error is small for a small time interval.
